# Implementing one-to-many relationship in Scala + Hibernate

Tags: scala, hibernate

I'm trying to implement a one-to-many relationship in Scala + Hibernate (one bank has many branches). I get the following error:

> Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non
>   collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:
>   admin.bank.manage.BankHib.branches

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE banks (
  sk int NOT NULL,
  code varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  version smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sk)
)

CREATE TABLE branches (
  sk smallint NOT NULL,
  code varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  descrip varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  bank_sk tinyint NOT NULL,   //  <== this is the bank sk column
  notes text,
  version smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  state char(2) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  county varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  county_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  zipcode varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sk)
)
```

And these are the Hibernate classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "banks")
class BankHib {

    @Id
    var sk: Int = _

    var code: String = _
    var name: String = _
    var version: Int = _

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="bank_sk") 
    var branches: Seq[BranchHib] = _
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "branches")
class BranchHib {

    @Id
    var sk: Int = _

    var code: String = _
    var name: String = _
    var descrip: String = _
    var city: String = _
    var county: String = _

    @Column(name = "county_id")
    var countyId: Int = _
    var state: String = _
    var zipCode: String = _
    var notes: String = _

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bank_sk", nullable=false)
    var bank: BankHib = _

    var version: Int = _
}
```

The error happens when I run a select of branches that should also retrieve related banks:

```
 val list = session.createQuery("from BranchHib order by name").list.
                          asScala.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[BranchHib])
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate [user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections) states:

> Hibernate uses its own collection implementations which are enriched with lazy-loading, caching or state change detection semantics. For this reason, persistent collections must be declared as an interface type. The actual interface might be `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.List`, `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Map`, `java.util.SortedSet`, `java.util.SortedMap` or even other object types (meaning you will have to write an implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType`).

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=false)
@JoinColumn(name="bank_sk") 
var branches: Seq[BranchHib] = _
```

You define `branches` to be a `Seq`, but Hibernate doesn't recognize Scala collection types. Change the type of `branches` to `java.util.List[BranchHib]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.List instead of Seq:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="bank_sk") 
var branches: java.util.List[BranchHib] = _
```